# Confirm function Javascript before closing the page on web app

Tags: javascript, vb.net, web-applications

Recently found this code for javascript:

```
function Confirm() {
         var confirm_value = document.createElement("INPUT");
         confirm_value.type = "hidden";
         confirm_value.name = "confirm_value";
        if (confirm("Are you sure you wish to sign out?")) {
           confirm_value.value = "Yes";
        } else {
          confirm_value.value = "No";
        }
        document.forms[0].appendChild(confirm_value);
};
```

I have this code on my aspx(UI) as part of the javascript code, it's a code on my button[Sign Out] on the client side, then will do more functions on the server side:

```
  <asp:Button ID="btnSignOut" runat="server" Text="" OnClick="btnLogOut_Click" OnClientClick="Confirm()">
```

On Code Behind (vb.net)

```
   Protected Sub btnSignOut_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)       
    Dim GlobalSessionVars As New GlobalSessionVariables
    Dim lang As String = GlobalSessionVars.USERS_LANGUAGE

    Try

        Dim confirmValue As String = Request.Form("confirm_value")
        If confirmValue = "Yes" Then
            Session.Clear()
            Response.Redirect(Constants.Url.MainPage + "?lang=" + lang, False)
        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        
    End Try
End Sub
```

It's working properly, but I need the message("Are you sure you wish to sign out?") inside the Confirm method to be dynamic depending the user language, which should be either french or english? I can translate of course the message itself from french to english, but I have to know how will I pass the variable containing that message for Ex. dim SignOutMessage ="Are you sure you wish to sign out?" from Code behind to the javascript code.

Answer (score 0):

Well, first up, when you have a asp.net button with BOTH a client side click event, and a client side click event?

You can prevent the button click from occuring WHEN the client side js code returns false.

You can use this effect to "remove" or reduce the amount of code you have.

So, that means you don't have "messy" code server side to test/check the value of some hidden field.

So, that code can work like this:

markup:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSignOut" runat="server" Text="Signout" 
    OnClick="btnSignOut_Click" 
    OnClientClick="return myconfirm()"
    /> 


<script>
    function myconfirm() {

        return confirm("Are you sure you wish to sign out?")

    }

</script>
```

So, if the user answers "Cancel" to the dialog, then the server side code NEVER runs, and thus you don't need all that extra messy code.

And don't use a funciton called "Confirm" when js has a built in function called confirm - (on a quest for world confusing here???).

Anyway, the above cleans up your code. So, just remember the js code can return true or false. And if false is returned, then the button click will not occur.

That means if the server side button code runs,  you can "assume" that ok was clicked.

Ok, next up and next part:

We want to pass some text from the server side for this dialog. There are MANY ways to do this (I can think of about 4-5 as I type this).

However, two good ways?

You can create a public VB function in the same web page, and have it return different text.

So, say we have this public function in the same web page - code behind:

```
Public Function logoutmessage() As String

    Dim sResult As String = ""
    Select Case lang
        Case 1
            sResult = "Are you sure you wish to sign out?"
        Case 2
            sResult = "Voulez-vous vraiment vous déconnecter ?"
    End Select

    Return sResult

End Function
```

Now, I don't have your lang setting, so replace that with whatever you are using to set/determine the language.

Now, our client side code becomes this:

```
        <asp:Button ID="btnSignOut" runat="server" Text="Signout" 
            OnClick="btnSignOut_Click" 
            OnClientClick="return myconfirm()"
            /> 

        <script>
            function myconfirm() {

                mymessage = "<%= Me.logoutmessage %>"
                return confirm(mymessage)

            }

        </script>
```

So, we used what is called a "server side" expression in the markup. On page load, asp.net will substitute that expression with the value of the function in the page code behind.

Another way? You could drop a hidden field on the page, and on page load set the value of the hidden field. And then in above code get/grab the value of the hidden field, and again display the message.

However, I think above is most simple, and no hidden fields or extra controls are required here.